# How can I finish a basement bathroom where the toilet plumbing is 12 inches from the foundation wall?

Tags: shower, framing

So I have a drain pipe that is 12 inches from the foundation wall.   Every shower floor pan I have looked at says you need 12 inches from the center of the drain to the wall.   I was planning on framing this bathroom and putting up drywall.

So for this particular wall, do I just put up furring strips so I can attach the shower wall up?   Or what can I do?   If I frame, the wall will then be like 8 inches from center which won't work.

Comment: If you're already at 12" you don't have room for furring strips (unless you find a tight-space shower, which reduces your options). What's your intention? Are you willing to cut concrete?

Comment: Shower drains usually have a boxed-out area to allow for adjustment. Is yours fully embedded in concrete?

Comment: Using Sheetrock in a shower? If you want Sheetrock and have limited room glue the Sheetrock to the walk with construction adhesive. I would make my own pan , not hard really since you are on a slab, that would be easier than cutting the slab and moving the drain.

Comment: First of all: don't use sheetrock in a shower, it's not intended for places that get wet.

Comment: Aren't you going to need to add a P-trap? In which case your shower drain won't be directly above the drain pipe in the concrete floor.

Comment: Ya I am hoping to avoid cutting into the concrete.  Will use green board for the shower area